# batch script change line

Tags: batch-file

I need to change the date in a batch file, this line is a parameter for backup software.

The file with the paramentros:TEXT.INI

```
[indexa] 
testindex=
[Restaurante_Geral]
FWHCOMPPREMEDIO= 
[backup] 
ultbackp=05/08/13
```

I need to change the line ultbackp=05/08/13, to current date.

I use the batch file below, but does not change the date if the parameter is already set.

```
@echo off
    SETLOCAL=enabledelayedexpansion
    SET YY=%DATE:~8,2%
    SET MM=%DATE:~3,2%
    SET DD=%DATE:~0,2%
    rename text.ini text.tmp
    for /f %%a in (text.tmp) do (
        set foo=%%a
        if !foo!==ultbackp set foo=ultbackp=%DD%/%MM%/%YY%
        echo !foo! >> text.ini) 
del text.tmp
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what is your current date today?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if "!foo:ultbackp=!" neq "!foo!" set "foo=ultbackp=%DD%/%MM%/%YY%"
```

Comment: Thank Endoro.

Now it worked properly, my comparison was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

ultbackup is not set to anything.  Therefore your compare is failing.